# Tensorflow : Assign variable by name

Tags: variables, scope, tensorflow, assign

I would like to assign/modify the values of my variables and I wish to do so by calling them by their name.

For exemple:

```
vars = tf.trainable_variables()
print(vars[1].name)
```

> 'matrix1:0'

```
upt = vars['matrix1:0'].assign_add(tf.constant(1))
sess.run(upt)
```

The reason for this is that indexes for variables aren't reliable as they are dependant as to when they are ran in the code. By adding a new variable, all the indexes would need to be shifted, which is not convenient. Using names would make my life much easier.

Comment: How about `vars={v.name:v for v in tf.trainable_variables()}`

Comment: Now, how do you assign new values to the variables by calling them by their name?

Comment: And then you can do `vars['matrix1:0'].assign_add(tf.constant(1))`

Comment: Great, works well! Thank you. 

Mind adding a reply so I can mark your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Python generator expression to construct a dictionary like this

```
vars={v.name:v for v in tf.trainable_variables()}
```

and then you modify the variable as

```
vars['matrix1:0'].assign_add(tf.constant(1))
```